# Building a parent/child array menu structure from SQL query result

Tags: php, recursion, menu, parent-child, arrayofarrays

I need to build a complex menu structure dinamically using a MySQL DB query. The query allows to define the menu items the user is entitled to use and see. The Menu structure is stored into a results set in a classic parent/child relation where each element has its own id and rely on its parent id. Parent id = 0 means there are no parents above that element (it's a root):

```
MNU_ID    MNU_FUNC    MNU_PARENT    MNU_ICON    MNU_TITLE_IT    MNU_TITLE_EN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1       FLTMGR      0             home        STATO FLOTTA    FLEET STATUS
  2       PSTN        0             map-marker  POSIZIONI       POSITIONS
  3       RTS         0             road        PERCORSI        ROUTES
  4       CHRTS       0             line-charts DIAGRAMMI       CHARTS
  ...
  13      MNLS        0             book        MANUALI         MANUALS
  14      RGLTNS      0             bank        NORMATIVE       REGULATIONS
  16      SPD         4             tachometer  VELOCITA'       SPEED
  17      ALT         4             area-chart  ALTITUDINE      ALTITUDE
  18      DST         4             exchange    DISTANZA        DISTANCE
  ...
  32      INSTL       13            book        INSTALLAZIONE   SETUP
  33      BASE        32            wrench      BASE            BASE
  34      FLPR        32            wrench      SONDA CARB.     FUAL PROBE
```

So as you can see the element 33 and 34 is under element 32, while element 32 is under element 13 and finally element 13 is has no parent as it's a root element (it's MNU_PARENT is 0).
Well having said that I've developed my code to return the following:

```
Array(
[FLTMGR] => Array(
    [icon] => fa fa-home
    [title] => STATO FLOTTA
    ),
[PSTN] => Array(
    [icon] => fa fa-map-marker
    [title] => POSIZIONI
    ),
[RTS] => Array(
    [icon] => fa fa-road
    [title] => PERCORSI
    ),
[CHRTS] => Array(
    [icon] => fa fa-line-charts
    [title] => DIAGRAMMI
    [sub] => Array(
            [SPD] => Array(
                [icon] => fa fa-tachometer
                [title] => VELOCITÁ
                ),
            [ALT] => Array(
                [icon] => fa fa-area-chart
                [title] => ALTITUDINE
                ),
            [DST] => Array(
                [icon] => fa fa-exchange
                [title] => DISTANZA
                ),
            [GSLN] => Array(
                [icon] => fa fa-tint blink
                [title] => CARBURANTE
                )
            )
        ),
...
[MNLS] => Array(
    [icon] => fa fa-book
    [title] => MANUALI
    [sub] => Array(
        [INSTL] => Array(
            [MNU_ID] => 32
            [MNU_FUNC] => INSTL
            [MNU_PARENT] => 13
            [icon] => fa fa-book
            [title] => INSTALLAZIONE
            [sub] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                    [MNU_ID] => 33
                    [MNU_FUNC] => BASE
                    [MNU_PARENT] => 32
                    [icon] => fa fa-wrench
                    [title] => BASE
                    ),
                [1] => Array(
                    [MNU_ID] => 34
                    [MNU_FUNC] => FLPR
                    [MNU_PARENT] => 32
                    [icon] => fa fa-wrench
                    [title] => SONDA CARB.
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
[RGLTNS] => Array( 
    [icon] => fa fa-bank
    [title] => NORMATIVE
    )
)
```

However as you can see I'm unable to produce the correct structure over the fisrt level. In other words if you look at INSTL element under MNLS there are the following errors:

1. The item MNU_ID,MNU_FUNC,MNU_PARENT should not be there (see the others)
2. The items under 'sub' have the same errors in 1.
3. The items under 'sub' should be identified by BASE, FLPR and not by 0 and 1

So the expected structure should be the following:

```
Array(
[FLTMGR] => Array(
    [icon] => fa fa-home
    [title] => STATO FLOTTA
    ),
[PSTN] => Array(
    [icon] => fa fa-map-marker
    [title] => POSIZIONI
[RTS] => Array(
    [icon] => fa fa-road
    [title] => PERCORSI
    ),
[CHRTS] => Array(
    [icon] => fa fa-line-charts
    [title] => DIAGRAMMI
    [sub] => Array(
            [SPD] => Array(
                [icon] => fa fa-tachometer
                [title] => VELOCITÁ
                ),
            [ALT] => Array(
                [icon] => fa fa-area-chart
                [title] => ALTITUDINE
                ),
            [DST] => Array(
                [icon] => fa fa-exchange
                [title] => DISTANZA
                ),
            [GSLN] => Array(
                [icon] => fa fa-tint blink
                [title] => CARBURANTE
                )
            )
        ),
...
[MNLS] => Array(
    [icon] => fa fa-book
    [title] => MANUALI
    [sub] => Array(
        [INSTL] => Array(
            [icon] => fa fa-book
            [title] => INSTALLAZIONE
            [sub] => Array(
                [BASE] => Array(
                    [icon] => fa fa-wrench
                    [title] => BASE
                    ),
                [FLPR] => Array( 
                    [icon] => fa fa-wrench
                    [title] => SONDA CARB.
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
[RGLTNS] => Array(
    [icon] => fa fa-bank
    [title] => NORMATIVE
    )
)
```

And now the code:

```
// $MenuDB contains the Menu structure returned by the DB

// Build the basic structure
$new = array();
foreach ($MenuDB as $a){
    $new[$a['MNU_PARENT']][] = $a;
    }

// Calls the recursive function CreateTree 
$tree = createTree($new, $new[0]);  

// Make final correction (remove unwanted items and replace index with keys)
$b=replaceKeys($tree);

print_r($b);
exit();

function replaceKeys(array $input) {    
    foreach($input as $key => &$val){                   // Scan the input array, each element will go in $val, the key will be $key
        $input[$val['MNU_FUNC']]=$input[$key];          // Replace index with key, the key is the value of the field MNU_FUNC
        if(is_numeric($key)) unset($input[$key]);       // Remove the item with numeric key (index) and leave the item with non-numeric index (key)
        unset($val['MNU_ID']);                          // Remove ID
        unset($val['MNU_PARENT']);                      // Remove Parent
        unset($val['MNU_FUNC']);                        // Remove Function
        if(isset($val['sub'])) {                        // avoid to work with undefined items
            if (is_array($val['sub'])) {                // check if there are childs inside the 'sub' item
                $val['sub'] = replaceKeys($val['sub']); // if we have childs, do it again recursively
                unset($val['url']);                     // remove url element if we have childs
                unset($val['url_target']);              // remove url_target element if we have childs
                }
            }
        }
    return $input;
    }

function createTree(&$list, $parent){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($parent as $k=>$l){
        if(isset($list[$l['MNU_ID']])){
            $l['sub'] = createTree($list, $list[$l['MNU_ID']]);
            }
        $tree[] = $l;
        } 
    return $tree;
    }
```

Despite my efforts I cannot figure out where is the error. 
Is there any alternaive to my workflow?

Comment: Can you use ajax...? Instead of this huge code...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use an Ajax call as this piece of code is used on the server-side script to build the framework menu. The only thing I can do is MySQL query and php script.

Comment: Can you show var_dump of data, that you geted from databese?

Comment: @J.Litvak $MenuDB contains the data from the DB exactly as you see in my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use only one recursive function:

```
function makeTree($array, $parent) {
    $return = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['MNU_PARENT'] == $parent) {
            $return[$value['MNU_FUNC']] = [
                'icon' => 'fa fa-' . $value['MNU_ICON'],
                'title' => $value['MNU_TITLE_IT'],
            ];
            $subs = false;
            foreach ($array as $search) {
                if ($search['MNU_PARENT'] == $value['MNU_ID']) {
                    $subs = true;
                }
            }
            if ($subs === true) {
                $return[$value['MNU_FUNC']]['subs'] = makeTree($array, $value['MNU_ID']);
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

$new = makeTree($arr, 0);
```

Comment: You're right ! +1 Your code works perfectly and your idea is right!
I've found the issue: the element INSTL has no childs but it's elements have childs!!! that's why the recursion stopped there. I'm going to post my reworked code as well...

Answer (score 0):

this code solved the issue:

```
$new = array();
foreach ($MenuDB as $a){
    $new[$a['MNU_PARENT']][] = $a;
    }

$tree = createTree($new, $new[0]);  

print_r($tree).PHP_EOL;

exit();


function createTree(&$list, $parent){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($parent as $k=>$l){
        if(isset($list[$l['MNU_ID']])){                       // check if current element has childs 
            $l['sub'] = createTree($list, $list[$l['MNU_ID']]); // build child structure inside 'sub'
            unset($l['url']);                                    // remove the 'url' item for elements having childs
            unset($l['url_target']);                             // remove the 'url_target' item for elements having childs
            }
        unset($l['MNU_ID']);                                    // remove the 'MNU_ID' item not needed anymore
        unset($l['MNU_PARENT']);                                // remove the 'MNU_PARENT' item not needed anymore
        //$tree[] = $l;
        $tree[$l['MNU_FUNC']]=$l;                               // while $tree[] = $l; will transfer the elements array to $tree using index, this one will will transfer the elements array to $tree using the key $l['MNU_FUNC'] 
        unset($tree[$l['MNU_FUNC']]['MNU_FUNC']);               // remove the 'MNU_FUNC' item not needed anymore 
        } 
    return $tree;
    }
```

This is shorter and even fatser!, we definitively don't need two passage so `replaceKeys` is not needed anymore we can do all the stuff inside `createTree`.